# Question on estimate in one of Jean Bourgain's 1992 papers

Tags: harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform, integral-transforms, oscillatory-integral

The paper in question is *[A Remark on Schrodinger Operators](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02808007)*.

---

The goal of the argument is to estimate the following integral:
$$K_1(x,y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{i(x-y)\cdot\xi+i(t(x)-t(y))|\xi|^2}\varphi_k(|\xi|)^2\,d\xi$$
where $t(x):x\in B(0,1)\mapsto t(x)\in(0,1)$ is arbitrary and $\varphi_k(|\xi|)$ is a Paley-Littlewood dyadic frequency projection to frequencies $2^{k-1}\le|\xi|\le 2^{k+1}$.
Bourgain then argues that by stationary phase in polar coordinates, we have
$$K_1(x,y)=2^{k/2} \varphi_k\left(\frac{|x-y|}{2[t(x)-t(y)]}\right) \frac{e^{i\frac{|x-y|^2}{4(t(x)-t(y))}}}{|x-y|^{1/2}|t(x)-t(y)|^{1/2}}+ O\left(\frac{2^{k/2}}{|x-y|}\right).$$
I wrote the integral as
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{i|x-y|r\cos\theta+i(t(x)-t(y))r^2}r\,\varphi^2_k(r)\,dr\,d\theta.$$
The phase is stationary at $r_0=\frac{|x-y|\cos\theta}{2[t(y)-t(x)]}$. Therefore, in the limit $|x-y|\to\infty$, I obtain the principal contribution to be
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\exp\left({i\frac{\cos(\theta)^2|x-y|^2}{4(t(x)-t(y))}}\right)\int_0^\infty \exp\left({2i[t(x)-t(y)](r-r_0)^2}\right)r\varphi_k(r)^2\,dr\,d\theta.$$
I believe I somehow need to use the support restriction on $\varphi_k$.
How do I get to Bourgain's result?

Disclaimer: I have initially posted the question to MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4646952/question-on-estimate-in-one-of-jean-bourgains-1992-papers) but realized MO is probably a better place for it.

Comment: Not an answer to your question at all, but perhaps a relevant comment from 10 years ago from Bill Johnson: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121751/inequality-on-trigonometric-polynomials#comment313394_121751

Comment: This doesn't surprise me at all, but thanks for the link. There could be an entire Stack Exchange site solely devoted to understanding Bourgain's many extra-terrestrial arguments (and I consider my question to not even be about a Bourgain-esque step, just a result of my lack of experience with stationary phase calculations).

Comment: what is strange is that $\phi_k$ appears quadratically in the first equation, but only linearly in the second equation; that must be a typo.

Comment: there is more strangeness: dimensional analysis gives that $x$ has the same dimension as $1/\xi$, while $t(x)$ has the same dimension as $1/\xi^2$; the integral in the first equation has dimension of $\xi^2$, but the integral in the second equation has dimension of $\xi^{3/2}$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, I do believe Bourgain meant $2^{k}$ (which is essentially the width of the annulus), as it is hinted in the lines following this calculation (explaining why one can ignore the error term). That might be the typo. Although I do not think the quadratic appearance of $\phi$ should effect anything, because as far as we are concerned, this is a projector operator/bump function.